# Как сформировать строку логина для программы?

Tags: c#, ajax, http

Здравствуйте, столкнулся со следующей задачей: надо программно зайти на www.svadba.com, у них даже есть свой api, но документация исчерпывающая. Пробовал кучу различных комбинаций login.svadba.com и так далее, на стековерфлоу сказали, что, возможно, процесс авторизации написан на ajax, Fiddler тоже не видит никаких post-запросов при авторизации, только get. Единственный post - там, где происходит выход с логина. Собственно, с этим и вопрос: что можно ещё попробовать сделать?

Answer (score 2):

"Документация исчерпывающая", у вас означает отсутствие или малый объем документации?

При отправке формы с главной страницы происходит AJAX-запрос на https://api.svadba.com/v2/identity. В случае если логин и пароль неверные возвращается ответ с 401 ошибкой. Если верный, то происходит редирект на страницу пользователя.

Таким образом, программно отправьте GET-запрос с логином и паролем (названия полей см в форме на странице) на страницу https://api.svadba.com/v2/identity.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Исчерпывающая документация означает её отсутствие
То есть, будет что-то вроде string s = GET("http://api.svadba.com/v2/identity", "/email=EMAIL&password=PASSWORD") ?
Простите, если вопрос очень глупый.

Comment: Не знаю С#, но думаю выглядеть будет что-то типа

WebRequest wrGETURL;
wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create("http://api.svadba.com/v2/identity?email=EMAIL&password=PASSWORD");

Подробно здесь http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/307023/ru

Comment: Пробовали мы с другом этот вариант, на выходе получаем ошибку 401, и, по сути, ничего:
https://pp.vk.me/c620231/v620231647/19fea/nrGMfcr9XyM.jpg

Comment: @Нутшелл: А вы уверены, что email правильный? Ну, или, может, вам надо подделать юзерагент/реферрер? Я бы на вашем месте спросил разработчиков сайта.

Comment: Да, входные данные абсолютно правильные, при обычном входе через браузер всё отлично. С разработчиками сайта нету связи, к сожалению. Спасибо за ответ, почитаю про Юзерагент!

Comment: У меня поля формы выводятся как ctl00$ctl22$ctl00$txtLogin и ctl00$ctl22$ctl00$txtPassword.

Comment: Да, так тоже пытались залогиниться, но получали 401. Может, там есть ещё какой-то параметр, типа browser, или ещё что..
Спасибо большое за ответ